# Display data received through GRPC client on web page

Tags: node.js, web, grpc, protocol-buffers

I'm new in the GRPC world. 
I need to display the data produced by some GRPC server on a webpage. 
So I created a nodejs client to receive the stream of data which is working fine, but I need to show the results on a webpage and I have no idea how to do so.
Any help would be welcome

Comment: Are you looking for a JS gRPC client that runs in the browser? Then gRPC-Web may be what you're looking for. If you are instead looking for a standard web UI for accessing arbitrary gRPC endpoints, this feature is not currently available in gRPC.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the beta grpc-web https://github.com/grpc/grpc-web to access the gRPC service from the web. This works by setting up a gateway in the middle as per the grpc-web documentation.

Comment: Could you elaborate more about grpc-web?